# Creating negative bar charts using CSS

Tags: css, charts, data-visualization

I've already asked a very similar question but that was using javascript/php - i've not had much luck finding an ideal solution so want try to emulate a chart using just CSS that looks similar to that below

As you can see the chart rows have a secondary element that is overlayed in a different colour & with a black border. This is the style that I am trying to achieve - can anyone suggest how to best go about this?

Can anyone suggest the best way to go about this possibly by creating another chart overlayed on top of another?

[image: negative bar chart]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My attempt at doing the chart with pure CSS http://dabblet.com/gist/3142994

... and a second version with a lot less HTML and cleaner CSS: http://dabblet.com/gist/3143479

Answer (score -2):

Instead of reinventing the wheel, in this case I'd recommend using an existing visualisation API. Google offer a fairly extensive one:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery

If you're feeling adventurous and this isn't what you're after, use `float: right;` to align the left bars to the right.

Comment: For all those down voting, I suggested a method to reinvent the wheel as well. It's also good practice to comment when down voting.